# Netty architecture - questions about NioWorker loop

Tags: netty

I am looking into the NioWorker.run() method and trying to understand how it works.
Below is the simplified version of the code:

```
    for(;;) {           
      try {
        SelectorUtil.select(selector);

        if (wakenUp.get()) {
          selector.wakeup();
        }

        cancelledKeys = 0;
        processRegisterTaskQueue();
        processWriteTaskQueue();
        processSelectedKeys(selector.selectedKeys());

      } catch (Throwable t) {
      }
    }
```

More-less it is clear what it does however I have some questions:

**1.** Selector.select(selector) performs selection with 500 millisecond timeout.
Why it is not just a blocking call?

**2.** What is the purpose of the below fragment? Why do we need to perform wakeup?

```
    if (wakenUp.get()) {
       selector.wakeup();
    }
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

1. We use a time-based blocking Selector.select(..) call because we also handle the registering of new channels to the worker via the processRegisterTaskQueue() method. If we would not use a time-based call we would get the risk to slow down things. We even changed the Selector.select(..) call to use 10ms in recent versions.
2. See the comment at [1]

[1] https://github.com/netty/netty/blob/3/src/main/java/org/jboss/netty/channel/socket/nio/AbstractNioWorker.java#L202

Comment: 1. As per my understanding blocking selector will unblock in case a new connection arrives, so you don't have to have time based call to make processRegisterTaskQueue called then.
2. The comment in attachment discusses only about the wakenUp.get(). I want to understand the reason why the selector has to be waken up at all? Is there more than one thread working with the selector?

Comment: New connections are accepted on the boss thread using a separate selector to the selector used by the IO-Worker to process the connection. The handover from boss selector to IO-Worker selector is handled by the boss thread placing tasks to register the new channel with the IO-Worker on a queue, which is then processed by the IO-Worker. The IO-Worker has to be woken up to process the queue.